# why is entropy/information gain the best measure in determining decision tree splits?

Tags: random-forest, entropy

So, let's say we're building a decision tree with 2D data.  Something like a set of X-Y pairs, and two classifications.  (think "petal width vs sepal width classifying to setosa vs virginica" like this: http://cogmaster-stats.github.io/python-cogstats/auto_examples/plot_iris_analysis.html)

I feel like I could say splitting on petal width = .9 is better then splitting on sepal width = 3 (or even petal width = .5, for example) because we have a "more pure" split. That is, on the next level of the tree, 100% of the training-data will be of one class.  Why is that ratio not good enough to determine how to split things?  To put it another way, why use the (somewhat less intuitive to understand) entropy calculation?